# Add control to Page.Controls in server control's code

Tags: asp.net

I want to add hiddenfield to Page.Controls in server control's code, but I've got exception "**The control collection cannot be modified during `DataBind`, `Init`, `Load`, `PreRender` or `Unload` phases.**" How to resolve this problem?

```
public class MyServerControl: Control
{
  HiddenField hf = new HiddenField{ID="hf"};
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
  {
    ...
    Page.Controls.Add(hf);
  }
}
```

Comment: In which block of page you are adding controls ?

Comment: My control is situated in layout and I want to add hiddenfield inside my control's code to Page.Controls. I've tried to do it inside control's OnInit and got this exception.

Comment: Could you please post all your code ?

Comment: can you share  some code

Comment: I've updated description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the error being thrown.  You can add the control either to an existing container (e.g. `Panel`) or use a `PlaceHolderControl` for its intended purpose.

The problem with dynamically adding controls (especially for postbacks) is that the ViewState is not very intelligent, and loads the controls in order.  Unless you're appending the control to the very end, you could end up with an invalid ViewState.

Comment: You should also add the control to your custom controls control collection, not the pages collection.